# holding wiring in place for a small child busy box

Tags: wiring

Seeking advice on wiring and rewiring a busy box for my young son (switches, lights & 5mm stereo jack).

All the wiring and batteries go inside a box, along with a breadboard so just the switched and lights are exposed.

I've been using tape and bluetac to secure the wires in place which is ok, but they fall our fairly frequently.

Are there any suggestions for other ways I could hold the wires in place that still allows me to rearrange the box for him from time to time?

Comment: subfloor adhesive Polyurethane from hardware store in tubes sparingly https://www.google.ca/search?q=subfloor+adhesive&num=30&client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL2ZGDhYTaAhURmoMKHfjyAxAQ_AUICigB&biw=1093&bih=1030

Comment: put a lid on the box

Comment: hotglue works well

Comment: Try Command hangers to see if they adhere to the plywood.  If so, you can tyrap your wires to them.  Also, would spiral wrap work?  Safety point:  Make the battery removable only with a tool so the child doesn't remove it.

Comment: you need to solder the wires, or at least use wago spring-lever nuts

Answer (score 1):

I use PL400 for everthing that needs this kind of strength with a dot and works much better than hotglue which is good for large surfaces but not small wires. Set time is 15 minutes but takes a day to cure and several days for full strength.

```
Waterproof and weather resistant, great for indoor and outdoor use
Cold weather gun-ability eliminates roll up on wet and frozen lumber
Meets and exceeds APA AFG-01 specs
Gap filling properties help to bridge minor gaps when bond irregular surfaces, reducing squeaking and splitting
High grab formula reduces the use of fasteners
Provides a strong durable bond to multiple surfaces
Low VOC formulation meets stringent State and Federal VOC regulations
Bonds dry, wet, frozen and treated lumber to most building materials
```

[image]
They use a white PU industrial version for electronics in power supplies for coils, caps and any large parts for stability.

Answer (score 0):

There are various types of adhesive cable clips you can stick to the inside of your box. The most common ones you find in the hardware store are often open-sided intended to resist gravity or snap over a specific size of cable, but you can also find ones which make a complete loop and so would be usable for securing many small wires.

A variant is to use plain cable ties a.k.a zip-ties, together with adhesive cable tie mounts, which are a sort of square pyramid shape which you can slip a cable tie through in one of two directions. This allows you to firmly snug down the cable tie, then clip it off later and replace it without needing to replace the mount.